# how is die Interpretation of this comprehension list

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

How can I understand this line?

```
O = [[[-1 for i in range(int(o[0][1]))] for k in range(int(i[0]))] for i in o]
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you need to understand.

Comment: thank you for the comments, but how could I transform this comprehension list  into basic for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could I transform this comprehension list into basic for loops?

Your list comprehension is basically three for loops in one. You could translate it like this:

```
O = []
for i in o:
   O1 = []
   for k in range(int(i[0])):
       O2 = []
       for j in range(int(i[0][1])):
           O2.append(-1)
       O1.append(O2)
   O.append(O1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is from the outside in:

- Set `O` to be equal to...
- an array consisting of, for each element `i` in the iterable `o`, ...
- an array consisting of, for each element `k` in `range(0,int(i[0]))`, ...
- an array consisting of, for each element `i` in `range(0, int(o[0][1]))`, ...
- -1.

So it will look like an array of arrays of arrays; something that looks like:

```
 [[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1], [], [-1, -1]]]
```

By the way, you'll want to change some variable names. `o` and `O` should not be used as single-letter variables for their similarity to `0`, and you have two nested `for` loops that are both using (and thus overwriting) `i` as their iterator.